# Como selecionar um radio ao clicar no texto ao lado dele?

Tags: html, css, formulário

É bem simples fazer fazer botões do tipo radio. Eu já vi uns inputs desse gênero por aí que permitem clicar diretamente dentro do circulo ou em cima do texto que se refere a cada botão radio.

Como que se faz isso?

Comment: Procure sobre `label` do HTML.

Comment: Oh... BEM mais simples do que eu poderia imaginar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você colocar o texto dentro de um elemento [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) que aponte para o ID do *input* correspondente:

```
<input type="radio" name="cores" id="vermelho"><label for="vermelho">vermelho</label>
<input type="radio" name="cores" id="verde"><label for="verde">verde</label>
<input type="radio" name="cores" id="azul"><label for="azul">azul</label>
```

Comment: Ou então `<label><input etc /></label>` que não precisa apontar pro ID ;)

Comment: É mesmo, não sei por que nunca faço isso!